# Xampp not working as per .htacces file

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

Refer below code

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /xyz/

 RewriteRule ^index.html(.*)$ index.php?page=mainIndex$1 [L,QSA]
```

Throw this error:

> Object not found 404

Comment: Provide the full detail e.g. what is your original url and what will be your rewritten url?

Comment: I _suspect_ this is an attempt to handle http get parameters in a `RewriteRule`, since I have no idea what that capture ground in the pattern should be meant to refer to otherwise... Note that such thing will not work, such parameters are _not_ part of the path component of the request URL that is processed by a rewriting rule.